# IEnumerable Select

Tags: c#, linq

Can someone explain why the following line of C# doesn't behave the same as the following foeach block?

```
string [] strs = {"asdf", "asd2", "asdf2"};
strs.Select(str => doSomething(str));


foreach(string str in strs){
  doSomething(str);
}
```

I put a breakpoint inside of doSomething() and it doesn't fire in the Select but it does with the foreach.

TIA

Comment: You should read the first few words of the remarks section in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx).

Comment: @ChaosPandion Your original comment was much better. ;)

Comment: @Marc - I wanted to be a bit more diplomatic as the OP may not know what deferred or execution means.

Comment: @ChaosPandion really the problem is less about deferred execution and more about the fact that he never uses the result of his operation.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: I'll assume your original statement was RTFM ;)  I read the MSDN entry for IEnumerable.Select, but failed to read the Remarks.  I see it now.  I do understand deferred execution.  Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Linq` query won't be processed until you convert it to an `Enumarable` using `ToList()`, `ToArray()`, etc.

And by the way the equivalent to your `foreach` statement is something like this:

```
strs.ForEach(doSomething);
```

```
strs.ToList().ForEach(doSomething);
```

or

```
Array.ForEach(strs, doSomething);
```

Comment: I'm assuming you mean Array.ForEach(str,DoSomething)

Comment: @dharga, Yes that's correct, I usually make mistakes when I'm writing code without testing, the correct version would be either `strs.ToList().ForEach(doSomething);` or `Array.ForEach(strs, doSomething);`

Comment: .Select() is lazy. Also, doSomething() must return a value, as .Select takes a (a -> b), or in .NET speak, it takes a Func<..>, not an Action<..>.

Answer (score 10):

This is because LINQ queries are deferred. The lambda passed to the `Select` method is actually executed when you access the result.

Try:

```
string [] strs = {"asdf", "asd2", "asdf2"};
var result = strs.Select(str => doSomething(str));

foreach(var item in result) {
}
```

Comment: the only thing I would say to this is that I prefer to have a static list to iterate over instead of the IEnumerable, if you intend on modifying the collection within your loop.

Answer (score 1):

you would need to do something like

```
string [] strs = {"asdf", "asd2", "asdf2"};
strs = strs.Select(str => doSomething(str)).ToArray();


foreach(string str in strs){
  doSomething(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think once you use the values returned from the select you'll see doSomething() called. Check out [yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) to see why this is happening.